# i am facing error during android development using kotlin while launching my application

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
java.lang.RuntimeException: 6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor found in modules jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1 (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1) and javax.activation-1.2.0 (com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0)
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file D:\trilok.programs\androidStudio\kotlinProject\AboutMe2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5d7120cf.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5b1b8080.). Check logs for more details.
com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource file D:\trilok.programs\androidStudio\kotlinProject\AboutMe2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5d7120cf.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@5b1b8080.
```

i have tried all solution suggested in stackoverflow, but i failed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]